# Highcharts windrose with one series without gap

Tags: highcharts

I've a area charts with

```
polar: true
```

which looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Uz4/

But I don't want the gap/space at the top. Is there any way to dispay this one series as closed area?

Thank you!
Torben

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way:

```
groupPadding: -0.125,
borderWidth: 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8Uz4/1/